# Because alt is not allowed on SVG image link, can I add a second display:none image to let Google see alt text?

Tags: seo, images, alt-attribute, hidden-text, svg

My developer has created a product page with images managed in this way:

```xml
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="original">
<image width="100%" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid slice"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xlink:href="http://www.sitename.it/letto_wind_overview.jpg"></image>
```

I can't use `alt` attribute for SEO here because it is not allowed in SVG.
Can I add another hidden image like:

```html
<img src="http://www.sitename.it/letto_wind_overview.jpg"
alt="letto wind">
```

with `display:none` attribute to make the `alt` attribute readable by Googlebot? Would that be good practice or could Google penalize me?

Comment: What makes you think Googlebot will take notice of an entirely hidden element? If an element is hidden and is never displayed then I would expect Googlebot to do its best to ignore it (at least in terms of having a positive influence on SEO).

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommending hiding your images with alttext as Googlebot might consider this to be cloaking and keyword stuffing. It could be very risky.

Sources on the web are saying to use `<title>alt text here</title>` when using images through xlink

Comment: This isn't "cloaking", since the element is presumably hidden for _everyone_, not just Googlebot.